# Unix expect script : parse HTTP output

Tags: expect

I have a expect script that tries to fetch homepage from of whatismyip site. I need to capture both - site's IP and HTTP return code:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set timeout -1
spawn telnet www.whatismyip.com 80
expect "Connected to www.whatismyip.com*"
set output $expect_out(0,string)
regexp {Connected to www\.whatismyip\.com.*?(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)} $output match ip
send -- "GET / HTTP/1.0\n"
send -- "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.4) Gecko/20070515 Firefox/2.0.0.4\n"
send -- "Host: www.whatismyip.com\n"
send -- "\n"
send -- "\n"
set output $expect_out(buffer)
regexp {.*HTTP/1.1 200 OK.*} $output match ret
puts $ip
puts $ret
expect eof
exit 0
```

There are two issue. Firstly I get the IP truncated by it last character and get error that variable ret not found:

```
spawn telnet www.whatismyip.com 80
Trying 108.162.200.37...
Connected to www.whatismyip.com (108.162.200.37).
Escape character is '^]'.
108.162.200.3
can't read "ret": no such variable
    while executing
"puts $ret"
    (file "./t2" line 15)
```

I tried all way and possibilities but cannot rectify both of them. Please let me know how to rectify this.

Comment: This might simplify your life: http://www.whatismyip.com/faq/automation.asp

Answer (score 0):

First issue: caused by the fact that you have no control of what * is in the $expect_out (imagine the characters are coming slowly and note that "Connected to www.whatismyip.com*" already matches just "Connected to www.whatismyip.com (108.16". Rather use:

```
set myexpr {Connected to www\.whatismyip\.com.*?(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)[^0-9]}; #Note the terminal condition!
expect {
   -re $myexpr {
         #now $expect_out(0,string) contains the right data to dig...
         regexp $myexpr $expect_out(0,string) match ip
   }
}
```

Second issue: note the expression in `regexp {.*HTTP/1.1 200 OK.*} $output match ret` doesn't contain brackets so `$ret` will never be filled even if the output contained that string, but I assume the $output was empty anyway, why?

Same as the first issue. Imagine the characters are coming slowly, at the time you do `set output $expect_out(buffer)` the characters were not received yet (the script itself is usually much faster that data transfer over the network and the buffer is set just after the data were sent, no wait for response). Again, use expect:

```
expect {
   "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" { 
        #do some stuff here ...
   }
}
```